# Make HTTP request for each link in a row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe `df_final` with a column link `df_final.link`.

The line below should take the links in each row of the DF and add what is returned (a string) to the column `full_article`

```
df_final['full_article'] = newspaper.fulltext(requests.get(df_final.link).text)
```

It works if I pass in manually a single URL in place of `df_final.link`in my `get()`, but doesn't seem to work otherwise, because it tries to pass all the series, not elements individually.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: newspaper.fulltext(requests.get(x).text)
df_final['full_article'] = df_final.link.apply(f)
```